# Is it bad practice to use triggers to increment revision number?

Tags: mysql

I'm building a commenting function and struggles a bit with the database design. The goal is to keep all history when a user decides to amend/delete a comment.

The columns that I imagine are

```
`commentID` int(11) NOT NULL,
`referencetype` char(1) NOT NULL,
`referenceID` int(11) NOT NULL,
`revision` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
`comment` text NOT NULL,
`userID` int(11) NOT NULL,
`deleted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`timestamp` int(11) NOT NULL,
```

When adding a new comment I want commentID to increment and when adding a revision to that same commentID I want the revision number to increment.

A possible solution would be

- Add a non-unique index on commentID and set it to auto_increment
- Add a unique index on (commentID, revision)
- Create a trigger that increment revision when inserting on existing commentID

Is this a reasonable solution? What might be a better way?

Edit: Sample data for some important columns

```
+-----------+---------------+-------------+----------+-----------------------+--+
| commentID | referencetype | referenceID | revision |        comment        |  |
+-----------+---------------+-------------+----------+-----------------------+--+
|         1 | A             |         123 |        1 | Comment1              |  |
|         1 | A             |         123 |        2 | Comment1 first edit   |  |
|         2 | A             |         123 |        1 | Comment2              |  |
|         1 | A             |         123 |        3 | Comment1 second edit  |  |
+-----------+---------------+-------------+----------+-----------------------+--+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the comment @daker put to the first version of this answer, I'd like to change the focus of this solution.

Instead of use an integer revision number, you could use the **timestamp field as revision**. Doing that, you can define your table like this:

```
`commentID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`referencetype` char(1) NOT NULL,
`referenceID` int(11) NOT NULL,
`comment` text NOT NULL,
`userID` int(11) NOT NULL,
`deleted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`timestamp` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
...
PRIMARY KEY(commentID, timestamp)
```

And then you will get these benefits:

- Your commentID is autoincremented
- You avoid to use an unecessary field, revision
- Every time an user modify a comment you will create a new entry into this table
- Every new registered will keep automatically the moment of the modification

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion however that would just overwrite the revision number and keep everything else. What I want is to keep the old record, insert a new record with the new data and with a revision number that is one bigger that the last revision with the same commentID.

Comment: I've modified my answer to adapt it to your comment, @daker

Comment: Sounds like a fair compromise. I would have to write some query to mock version numbers (for presentation purposes) but that shouldn't be a problem. Thanks for your help!